# WITHOUT using a loop, extract year and month from panda series with entries in type pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe column looks like this:

```
df['START_TIME_object']
0        2021-01-05 00:00:00-08:00
1        2021-01-29 00:00:00-08:00
2        2021-01-10 00:00:00-08:00
3        2021-01-03 00:00:00-08:00
4        2021-01-11 00:00:00-08:00
```

Each entry in this column (panda series) is of type pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp.

I can extract year and month each row of this panda series by using

```
test = df['START_TIME_object'][0].tz_localize(None)
test.year, test.month
```

But this requires me to loop through each row which is not very clean. How can I do this in a cleaner code without explicitly looping through each row?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `dt` accessor:

```
df['START_TIME_object'].dt.year
df['START_TIME_object'].dt.month
```

Comment: I tried this before. that does not work. `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`. The entry is not datetime.

Comment: It should work with timestamps just fine. Check for incorrectly parsed values that are not timestamps.

Comment: again, what you are suggesting does not even work for one entry and neither the panda data series which is what I am searching for. See the first two rows data youself. You can also construct a two row data frame and check yourself
0    2021-01-05 00:00:00-08:00
1    2021-01-29 00:00:00-08:00
Name: START_TIME_object, dtype: object